# How to Disable F11 key

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I want to disable the <kbd>F11</kbd> key in my Silverlight application because I don't want a user to switch to full-screen mode.

Or is there a way I can write my code for <kbd>F11</kbd> key event? I tried with key down event , but not working for <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> and set of other keys .

Comment: There are much simpler ways to annoy your users.  Try rapidly flashing the background of your app, or perhaps create tons of popup windows.

Comment: Thanks Will for your Comments , But Here that is a functionality we need and required by the user. Ofcourse nobody wants to annoy there users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the browser has precedent over the Silverlight plugin.

You could use Javascript to disable key input. Here's a blog post about how:
[Disable ctrl + n and other ctrl + key combinations in JavaScript](http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/disable-ctrl-n-and-other-ctrl-key-combinations-in-javascript.html)

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight prohibits switching to and from fullscreen mode except when handling a user event (such as clicking a button or link), so there is no way of detecting that a user goes full-screen and then reverting it.

From what I can find in the documentation, there is also no way of preventing an application going fullscreen.

On the other hand, MSDN states that a Silverlight application can only work in two-ways: embedded or fullscreen. So if you embed your application this should not be a problem, because full-screen switching in an embedded Silverlight application will only happen if you set `Host.Content.IsFullScreen` to true.

Read more about [Silverlight and fullscreen support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189023(VS.95).aspx).

Comment: I believe he is talking about the browser's full screen mode, not Silverlights. Most web browsers will expand to fill as much screen real estate as possible when you hit F11 - the Browser still shows its navbar and tabs however. The closest possible answer might be rdkleine's answer, but it's still something users could override.